# simple way of getting columns for numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some object `y`.
If `directed`, y a tuple (y0, y1) of shape (n, d) arrays.
If `not directed`, y is a single array of shape (n, d).

Furthermore, y/y0/y1 of type `np.ndarray` can be either 1d or 2d. If 1d, I want its length. If 2d, I want the second value of its shape.

I'm trying to think of the simplest code that accounts for all of this and gives me the value of `d`. So far, the simplest I have is

`_, d = np.atleast_2d(y[0]).shape if directed else np.atleast_2d(y).shape`

but this feels a little obtuse. Can anyone think of a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a budget for the number of lines you're allowed to use, then something like this is nice and simple (you could even add explanatory comments for bonus points):

```py
if directed:
    [y0, y1] = y
    d = y0.shape[-1]
    assert y1.shape[-1] == d
else:
    d = y.shape[-1]
```